# Can't see variables or hit breakpoint in VS Code in brand new Yeoman - Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, debugging, webpack, office-js

I'm trying to get debugging working in my Office Add-In for Excel in VSCode. After being only able to see "Call Stack" in VSCode and spending considerable time, I decided to download a brand new `yo office` template and see if it worked and compare.

I had to install `office-addin-debugging` and `webpack` globally but I am able to now fire up webpack server, launch Excel, open Taskpane (I chose Taskpane Add-In w/ Javasript for Excel) and hit run button.

But, in VSCode I don't hit my breakpoint I added to `commands.js` and I can't see any variables under `watch`. This is the same behaviour my project showed, but I'm just using `http-server` for my main project and `webpack` purely for bundling/polyfill etc.

So main question is, **can you debug the initial template from `yo office` or what else needs to be configured?**

And for my project, do I need to use `webpack dev server` as I know/see it has "hot-reload" capabilities, but I don't plan on debugging/testing w/ bundled code, just straight on the source code.

I've been following this --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium and you can see in the below screenshot that its using Edge Chromium.

A few details:

I'm on Windows 10, w/ up to date VS Code and NodeJS (reinstalled during testing w/ my project)

**Update:**

Ok so two things I was doing wrong...

- Had to start in **Admin Mode for VSCode**
- Was using `commands.js` but the template didn't load that file, needed to **use `taskpane.js`**

**I'm able to hit breakpoints, but the variable I declared and `watched` is showing `undefined`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Further Update:

- I was able to debug w/o using "Web-pack" and in fact that was the only way I've been able to see variables in VSCode

I started Webserver via:

```
  "webserver:https:src": "http-server ./src/ -S -C %USERPROFILE%/.office-addin-dev-certs/localhost.crt -K %USERPROFILE%/.office-addin-dev-certs/localhost.key --cors . -p 3000",
```

I found that the `commands.js` I was editing, wasn't working, but if I clicked `commands.js` in the `debug` console, I was able to edit the file that was being hosted on the webserver..

Example, if you look below, you can see the file URL is `http://localhost..` vs `src/...`.

This means I have  to load Excel, open taskpane, open file on webserver, insert breakpoint and reload.

I swear I had it in sync once w/ local files when I opened DevTools, I was able to `set root folder`, but next time I opened Excel/DevTools this option was gone and so was the sync..

I'm close, but not quite there. **Does VSCode need to start the Webserver? I have it running separately in another terminal..**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Blackcat unfortunately, you have to wait a certain period after answering, so I couldn't until today, but will do! PS: In the future, I'd make this comment on the answer for this, not OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out! The last thing to do was to correctly set the `"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/"` adding the `/src/` part.

To recap:

- VSCode must be launched in Admin Mode
- I prefer not to use Webpack for WebServer, I used `http-server` and serve the `/src/` directory untranspiled/minified etc..

  ```
  "webserver:https:src": "http-server ./src/ -S -C %USERPROFILE%/.office-addin-dev-certs/localhost.crt -K %USERPROFILE%/.office-addin-dev-certs/localhost.key --cors . -p 3000 -c-1",
  ```

Final `launch.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Edge - Excel Desktop Localhost External",
  "type": "msedge",
  "request": "attach",
  "port": 9229,
  "timeout": 42000,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/",
  "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop Localhost External",
  "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug Localhost External"
},
```